# Tf.keras.Model class ~ self variables performance

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow2.0

**EDITED:**

It turned out that the base class much higher in the inheritance tree inherited `Tf.keras.Model` when this class inheritance is present the below described behaviour is observable. The performance of a plain Python class is negligible compared to the plain script.

I haven't found any related documentation of this behaviour, if available updates will follow.

**EDIT 2:**

I have not found any documentation about this (so a confirmation is needed) but it appears that:
If I assign any object to `self` (in a `Tf.keras.Model` inheriting class) all the contained `tf.Variables` gets extracted and appears in the `trainable_variables` attribute of the class. So my assumption is that `keras.Model` inspects any assignment to `self` trying to find some specific objects, and this inspection causes the `self` assignment of a huge dict to be slow.

*For reference: Inspection gets deep in nested lists and dictionaries but do not inspect classes unless they extends `ts.keras.Model` or `tf.keras.Layer`*

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have an list `col` of strings (~300k rows of ~30 char strings to give you an idea). To be precise is a `pandas.DataGrid` not a list.

I'm creating a lookup dictionary for future use like so:

```
direct = {}
inverse = {}
# progressive
progressive = 0

# create direct map
for label in col:
    # skip if present
    if str(label) in direct:
        continue
    # else add to direct
    direct[str(label)] = progressive
    inverse[progressive] = str(label)
    progressive += 1
```

Nothing strange here, it takes 0.15 seconds and python process memory usage is reasonable.

Then I moved my code in a class, and here things get strange. Here are provided two slightly different versions of the same function.

Version A:

```
def fromDataset(self, column):
    # reset map
    self.direct = {}
    self.inverse = {}

    # progressive
    progressive = 0

    # create direct map
    for label in column:
        # skip if present
        if str(label) in self.direct:
            continue
        # else add to direct
        self.direct[str(label)] = progressive
        self.inverse[progressive] = str(label)
        progressive += 1
```

Version B:

```
def fromDataset(self, column):
    # reset map
    direct = {}
    inverse = {}

    # progressive
    progressive = 0

    # create direct map
    for label in column:
        # skip if present
        if str(label) in direct:
            continue
        # else add to direct
        direct[str(label)] = progressive
        inverse[progressive] = str(label)
        progressive += 1

    self.direct = direct
    self.inverse = inverse
```

All the proposed functions yeld the same result (a dictionary of ~120k entries with a ~30MB RAM footprint)

I can accept that Version A will be slower than Version B accessing `self` variables may times but what I can't understand is how is possible that Version B is taking 2.16 seconds (14x than before) weather Version A can not even be tested (After 10+ minutes no result yet and the process memory usage grows by 500+ MB)

What is even more strange Version B is taking 0.17 seconds to create the dictionaries and ~2 seconds to perform:

```
self.direct = direct
self.inverse = inverse
```

After an entire day lost with this I started wondering if there is something related with Python memory allocation that I'm missing. And the only meaningful assumption I came to is that `self.direct = direct` causes Python to actually move/copy the dictionary in ram.

Can anyone explain me what is going on in Version A and in Version B that so radically differ from the straight scripted version?

Comment: I presume you are only calling "fromDataSet" once, right?  If you call this function a lot, one issue is that for A, you keep erasing the data in self.direct and self.inverse when it is called.

Comment: Yes. Sure of that, i have isolated tests properly. I have logging and timing in this functions (that I have not included in the post for clarity)

Comment: Maybe you should post thee whole class so we can see how you wrote it.  There may be outliers we arent aware of.

Comment: There is information missing there - a plain Python class would no way take this long - but if you are writting a class using as basis an instrumented class in whcih attribute access is guarded, then it is another story.  By the time increase you mention on the `self.direct = direct` assignment alone, it is easy to say that there is some code being triggered that scans the whole "direct" data structure doing some mapping or something.

Comment: True. It seems that the base class few classes higher implemented tf.keras.Model and this somehow affects self assignments

Comment: I will edit the question to point this out, but leave it, for respect to the below answer effort. I would be glade if someone can edit it to further explain how keras.Model affects the class behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a reproducible example and encountered no issue :

```
import random
import string

import pandas


def gen_random_word(word_length=30):
    return ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(word_length)))

# I create a list of 300000 labels (but only 150k distinct labels) of 30 characters
labels = [gen_random_word() for _ in range(150000)]
labels = labels + labels
random.shuffle(labels)

# A dataframe here is useless but I try to get close to your own example
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'labels': labels}
)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.direct = {}
        self.inverse = {}
        self.progressive = 0

    def fromDataset(self, column):

        # create direct map
        for label in column:
            # skip if present
            if str(label) in self.direct:
                continue
            # else add to direct
            self.direct[str(label)] = self.progressive
            self.inverse[self.progressive] = str(label)
            self.progressive += 1

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.direct = {}
        self.inverse = {}
        self.progressive = 0

    def fromDataset(self, column):
        # reset map
        direct = {}
        inverse = {}

        # progressive
        progressive = 0

        # create direct map
        for label in column:
            # skip if present
            if str(label) in direct:
                continue
            # else add to direct
            direct[str(label)] = progressive
            inverse[progressive] = str(label)
            progressive += 1

        self.direct = direct
        self.inverse = inverse
        self.progressive = progressive
```

First test :

```
%%time # remove that if you are not using jupyter and use another timing solution

direct = {}
inverse = {}
# progressive
progressive = 0

# create direct map
for label in df['labels']:
    # skip if present
    if str(label) in direct:
        continue
    # else add to direct
    direct[str(label)] = progressive
    inverse[progressive] = str(label)
    progressive += 1
```

Wall time : 267 ms

Second test :

```
%%time
a = A()
a.fromDataset(df['labels'])
```

Wall time : 249 ms

Third test :

```
%%time
b = B()
b.fromDataset(df['labels'])
```

Wall time : 220 ms

So... nothing significant.

Comment: Yeour reproduction is right. I've removed anything from the class (i mean other functions and even anchestor classes) and execution now is normal. By testing each single super class i've found one in the project that is inheriting Tf.keras.Model - it is possible that keras model modifies memory management on non @tf functions? (When I inherit it again the behaviour changes to as described by me)

Comment: well of course tf.keras.Model can do a lot of stuff that affects the memory and execution time.

Comment: If you know more about it I would like you to update your answer, thank you.